# Add comment in RCS

Tags: shell, rcs

Is there a way to automatically add a comment when updating a file in RCS?
For example, I am writing a script, and one of the functions will co -l a file, make changes, then ci -u.  Now at that point, RCS waits for a comment to be entered.  I want the comment to be automatically added so the script does not stop at that point.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-m` option to `ci` accepts a messages string.  No space is permitted after the `-m`:

```
ci -u -m'This is a message' file
```